# ffmpeg tee mux option for restreaming a single input to multiple destinations without transcoding using Copy

Tags: ffmpeg, tee

Wanted to stream or `"restream"`" to multiple outputs using the tee mux but it appears that the `copy` flags don't seem to work.

Wanted to try something like this:

```
ffmpeg -re -i /home/video/test.mp4 -map 0 -flags +global_header -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict -2 -f tee "[f=flv]rtmp://server1.ip:1935/live/test1|[f=flv]rtmp://server2.ip:1935/live/test2"
```

But it appears that I have to `transcode` meaning I have to do `-c:v libx264...` which takes away valuable `CPU` usage.

Is there anything I am not doing right with the above command?